# Looking for a jQuery File Uploader

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I am wondering if anyone knows of a jQuery file uploader that has downgrade support (so if the user does not have Flash it will use HTML 5, and if the user does not have either then that's too bad).

I know of [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) but I don't see myself allowing multiple file uploads so I don't want such a big area consumed by the uploader. I rather it just be a textbox and browser button (or something in those lines) that does not take up so much space.

I am using asp.net mvc 3 so it should be able to connect to the server and not need some PHP files or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)? It seems to be the gold standard.

Comment: Ya. I looked into it but it does not seem have a downgrade.

Answer (score 2):

This jquery plugin has downgrade option and has some good documentation http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Ya, I saw this one but I could not find if it was using flash or what it was using. Where does it say that is downgrades(and to what?)

Comment: It doesn't use flash to upload files.IT uses iframe technique to upload files in case the browser doesn't support HTML5 else uses the HTML5 file API.

Comment: @chobo2: From the [readme](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/README.md): "**Graceful fallback for legacy browsers:** Uploads files via XMLHttpRequests if supported and uses iframes as fallback for legacy browsers."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really nice looking solution, and unlike others, is pure jQuery (**no Flash®, no PHP**)...

http://uniformjs.com/

It uses customizable themes and can be applied to all of your form elements.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using ajax as well. So I think I need like html5 or flash as my understanding was javascript can't access the file system and that causes a problem with trying to do an uploader in ajax.

Comment: @chobo2, you said you don't require multiple file upload capabilities, so then the browser's default file upload element will work:  `<input type="file">`.  If that's true, then you can use this to make it look consistent cross browser.  It only alters the look & feel of the standard form element.

Comment: I still don't think that will work if I am serializing the form and sending it through ajax. can you provide an example?

Comment: @chobo2, Can _you_ provide an example?  Does your form work by using `<input type="file">` or not?